# bash scripting: build a command then execute

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to make a function that basically takes in arguments like `f hello there my friend` and searches a directory using `find` for all occurences of any of those strings, so it would be `find | grep 'hello\|there\|my\|friend'`.  I'm new to shell scripting, but my code is below:

```
function f { 
  cmd="find | grep '"
  for var in "$@"
  do 
    cmd="$cmd$var\\|"
  done
  cmd="${cmd%\\|}'"
  echo "$cmd"
  $cmd 
}
```

When I execute the command, I get this:

```
# f hello there my friend
find | grep 'hello\|there\|my\|friend'
find: `|': No such file or directory
find: `grep': No such file or directory
find: `\'hello\\|there\\|my\\|friend\'': No such file or directory
```

Why does it not work, and how can I make it work?  I imagine it's something to do with the string not being converted to a command, but I don't know enough about how shell scripting works to figure it out.

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: Wait... you want to search these strings in the _file name_ or in the _content of the file_?

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf the filenames. Searching the content is done with `grep -r`

Comment: Ok for the _file name_: so are you looking for the _full path_ or just the name of the file? because your method will include all files in a given directory if the directory name matches the string.

Answer (score 11):

It looks like your command syntax is correct. To run the command from a script in bash and capture the result, use this syntax:

```
cmd_string="ls"
result=$($cmd_string)
echo $result
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of piping the output of `find` through `grep`, you might as well use the full capabilities of `find`. You'll want to build up a an *array* that contains the options:

```
-false -o -name '*string1*' ... -o -name '*stringn*'
```

to pass to `find` (where `string1` ... `stringn` are the strings passed as arguments):

```
f() {
   local i args=( -false )
   for i; do
      args+=( -o -name "*$i*" )
   done
   find "${args[@]}"
}
```

We're using `-false` as an initializer, so that building up the array of options is simple; this also has the benefit (or flaw, depending on your point of view) that if no options are given then `find` exits early without listing all the content of the directory recursively.

With `grep` you could use regexes to have more powerful matching capabilities; here we're using `find`'s `-name` option, so we can only use the basic globs: `*`, `?` and `[...]`. If your `find` supports the `-regex` option (GNU `find` does), and if you *really* need regexes, then it's trivial to modify the previous function.

---

Another possibility is to use Bash's extended globs:

```
f() (
   IFS='|' eval 'glob="$*"'
   shopt -s globstar extglob nullglob
   IFS=
   printf '%s\n' **/*@($glob)*
)
```

A few things to note here:

- The whole function is included in a subshell—it's not a typo. That's to simplify a few things: no need to use local variables, and no need to save the shell options to restore them at the end of the function.
- The first line uses the *evil* `eval` but in a safe way: it's actually an idiomatic way to join the elements of the positional parameters with the first character of `IFS` (here a pipe character).
- We need to set `IFS` to the empty string so as to avoid word splitting in the glob `**/*@($glob)*`.
- The glob `**/*@($glob)*` uses `globstar` and the `extglob` `@($glob)` (with no quotes, it's not a typo). See [Pattern Matching](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching) in the reference manual.

This function uses Bash's extended globs, that differ from (and aren't as powerful as) regexes (yet this should be enough for most cases).

Answer (score 4):

I got here because it was the only google SO hit for when I wanted to build a commandline and my parameters included spaces.

The solution was to use a bash array:

```
#! /bin/bash
# using /bin/sh here might work if sh is broken or mapped to bash but this is not compatible with a real sh.
MY_ARGS=( "--HI" "--there" "--With spaces" )
if [ "X$OPTIONAL" != "X" ] ; then MY_ARGS+=( "$OPTIONAL" );fi
MY_ARGS+=( "$@" )

my_command "${MY_ARGS[@]}"
```

Adapted from: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Answer (score 3):

Don't put the entire command in a string; just build the argument for `grep`

```
f () { 
  local grep_arg=''
  delim=''
  for var in "$@"; do
      grep_arg+="$delim$var"
      delim='\|'
  done
  echo "find | grep '$grep_arg'"
  find | grep "$grep_arg"
}
```

Comment: this is appending to `grep_arg` every time I run it (i.e. the value of `grep_arg` persists).  why is that happening?

Comment: Sorry, variables are global by default in shell. I'll update

Answer (score 1):

The most universal way: you can use symbols like "|" (pipe) and other variables into the input and get the result from stdout.

```
function runcmd(){
  eval "$1"
}

result=$(runcmd "Any command ${here}")
```

Comment: It could be intersting to add an example with the pipe you explain in the begining of tour answer?